# If $B$ is the restriction of an operator $A$ to an invariant closed subspace, is there an inclusion relation between $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(B)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a linear operator on a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $E$ and $K$ be a closed subspace of $E$ such that $A$ is $K$-invariant, i.e. $$A(\mathcal D(A)\cap K)\subseteq K.\tag1$$

> Under the given assumptions, $B:=\left.A\right|_{\mathcal D(A)\:\cap\:K}$ is a linear operator on the $\mathbb R$-Banach space $K$. How are the spectra $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$ and resolvent sets $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(B)$ of $A$ and $B$ related? Can we show inclusion relations between them?

Comment: I have just given jour problem a fast overview. I would split the spectrum of $B$ into the pointwise, continuous and residual part, and show that each of those is contained in the respective part of the spectrum of $A$ (there is the exception of the continuous spectrum of $B$ which should split among the continuous and the residual spectrum of $A$).

Comment: If $A$ is self-adjoint (or more generally if $K$ admits an $A$-invariant complement) then it should be $\sigma(B)\subseteq \sigma(A)$, ie $\rho(B)\supseteq \rho(A)$. If that is not the case you have no guarantees (a simple bounded example is the left-shift on $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$ restricted to $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$, its spectra are $\{-1,1\}$ and $\{0\}$ respectively).

Comment: @s.harp What exactly do you mean by "$K$ admits an $A$-invariant complement"? And regarding your counterexample: Did you intend to restrict the left-shift on $\ell(\mathbb Z)$ to a different space (restricting to the same space doesn't really make sense)?

Comment: A complement would be a subspace $K'$ so that $K\oplus K'=E$ and $A(K')\subseteq K'$. Also the example is wrong since I mixed up left and right shift at two points. The right shift operator $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)\to\ell^2(\Bbb Z), \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} x_k e^k\mapsto \sum_{k} x_k e^{k+1}$ sends $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ to itself (the left shift doesn't do that), hence we are in your situation. The right shift on $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$ is unitary, hence has spectrum on the unit circle (since we are in $\Bbb R$-vector spaces subset of $\pm1$). The spectrum of the shift operator on $\ell^2(N)$ is $[-1,1]$ (not  $\{0\}$).